# querySelector for skipping elements

Tags: javascript, css, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a question about the querySelector. is there a way to search for all p elements in an html file but skip those p elements who are in a specific div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
     <p>hit</p>
     <p>hit</p>
     <p>hit</p>
     <div>
         <p>hit</p>
         <p>hit</p>
         <p>hit</p>
         <p>hit</p>

     </div>
 </div>
<div class="donthit">
    <p>dont</p>
    <p>find</p>
    <p>us</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thats my example html. is there a way to get all p elements but not the ones in div  class = "donthit"?

Comment: By using `element.parentNode` you can get the `p`'s parent element. Then, check if that parent element has the `className="donthit"`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman and because no one saw you, you decide to close as duplicate?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Looks like a poor dupe to me. It's the same.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it's not the same, the duplicate is about implementing not selector .. here it's about to find the correct selector that may involve the not selector

Comment: Er... Kinda confused. You sure it's not the dupe?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman no it's not ... the dup is about to select element where a class should not exist, here it's about selecting element where a parent element shoud not have a particular class. So it's not a direct dup even if it can be related ... there is probably more suitable ones

Comment: @TemaniAfif Makes sense, would you like to propose a better dupe?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman and why? you already went so fast to vote to delete and sent a del vote on SOCVR ... you didn't even give the time to the OP to interact with the question or even check the dupe. Even if it's an *easy* question for you, it's still a valid question and we should give the OP the time to read the dupe, not delete his question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well the OP will have access to the question and answers.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman after deletion he cannot access them anymore. We need 10k rep to see deleted questions ... in all the cases, we need to give him a chance to interact with his question. I don't think it's necessary to send a delvote to SOCVR

Answer (score 2):

You can first get all the divs without the specific one then find the `p` element inside:

```js
$('div:not(.donthit)').children('p').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>hit</p>
  <p>hit</p>
  <p>hit</p>
  <div>
    <p>hit</p>
    <p>hit</p>
    <p>hit</p>
    <p>hit</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="donthit">
  <p>dont</p>
  <p>find</p>
  <p>us</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .not() method or :not() selector

Code based on your example:

```
$("div:not(.donthit)").children("p")   // not selector 
$("div").not(".donthit").children("p") // not method
```

Comment: the class isn't applied to the p element